# Using "as much" at the end of a sentence

Tags: meaning

What does **as much** mean in this sentence:

> You may not mind the sound of your voice as much?

Answer (score 1):

“As much” means in the following sentence “to the (almost) same degree” (as something else or as some other time, you would compare it to something, based on the context). See https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+much

> You may not mind the sound of your voice as much?